# Cassndra/Spark Correlating Data points seperated by million record

Tags: cassandra, apache-spark, bigdata

I have sensor data and the approx format shows the way i am storing it in a cassandra table.

```
CREATE TABLE sensor_log (
    sensor_id BIGINT,
    created_at TIMEUUID,
    SensorEventType TEXT,
    PRIMARY KEY(sensor_id, created_at)
)
WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (created_at DESC)
```

There are like 10 different types of events(SensorEventType) which occur. Say they are named

```
(SensorEventType)SET1...SET10.
```

And i am keeping the data for 90 days.

Some of these types of events occur quite frequent and some are very infrequent.

so what is happening is SET1 occurs say on day1 and SET9 occurs on after day 60. In Between this there are many other SensorEventType records which are logged. So in between there will be 100 Millions of data points.

```
example

SENSOR_ID   Data stored Clustered by created_at.
 1         SET2,SET1,SET3,SET4....100millionrandomSET....SET9,SET3,SET4....
 2         SET4,SET5,SET1,SET4....100millionrandomSET....SET2,SET9,SET6....

each SET stored in sequential manner by created_at
```

I need to correlate for each sensor the fact that SET1 AND SET9 data points in a logic to derive some information. I am thinking of using spark for the same. 
The Correlation is purely based on the SensorEventType and is the business logic requirement to find the time duration between the SET9 and SET1. So If SET9 happened after SET1 then note the time duration between the occurrence and save it in another table.

Now the question is in order to correlate the data in Spark it seems that i need to actually load all the data points , all million of them in memory to correlate between SET1 AND SET9. Is that a right way to think about solving this design problem.

Any one has better pointers to how this should be designed and how correlation in spark across million in between data point would work. I am new to spark, any help would be appreciated in understanding.

Comment: Could you give some more details on how you determine that two of your data points are correlated?  Do you apply a function to both and if the result matches, then they are correlated?

Comment: The Correlation is purely based on the SensorEventType and is the business logic requirement to find the time duration between the SET9 and SET1. So If SET9 happened after SET1 then note the time duration between the occurrence and save it in another table.

Comment: @Yatin - must the two events have the same `sensor_id` to be correlated or do you simple look for the first SET9 after SET1? Anyway some filter and sort will be probably needed.

Comment: @Marmite yes the correlation is between differents events of same sensor. (sensor_id) ? I am simplifying the question above so it can be more readable.

Comment: @Yatin `it seems that i need to actually load all the data points` - I probably doesn't get it fully, but what about to load only the the relevant event types (SET1 + SET9), sort them on sensor_id and timestamp and calculate the interval for cases where SET9 follows SET1 with the same sensor_id?

Comment: @Marmite i was thinking of loading all of them at one time because the way i was thinking was applying a series of functions doing business logic to same set of Data. In one business case i would need only (SET1 , SET9) and then next would need(SET4,SET6)...may be doing all functions at once may not be the most optimal way as it may lead to unnecessary load on system to fetch everything in between.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I fully understand your use case, but it seems like perhaps you don't need to use Spark and could do this correlation in plain Cassandra.

Instead of (or perhaps in addition to) your table that records all events for a sensor in a single partition, why not add the event type to the partition key like this:

```
CREATE TABLE sensor_log (
    sensor_id BIGINT,
    created_at TIMEUUID,
    SensorEventType TEXT,
    PRIMARY KEY((sensor_id, SensorEventType), created_at)
)
WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (created_at DESC)
```

This will put each SET value in its own partition for each sensor that you can query independently.

By doing that, the 100 million data points in between SET1 and SET9 events  would be put in separate partitions and would not get in your way.  So when a SET9 event comes in, just select the most recent data point from the SET1 partition for that sensor:

```
SELECT created_at FROM sensor_log WHERE sensor_id=x and SensorEventType=SET1 LIMIT 1;
```

Now you subtract that created_at time from the created_at time of the incoming SET9 event.

Partitioning like this would also simplify using Spark since you would create RDD's from these smaller partitions, and only load the SET1 and SET9 partitions instead of all the SET types.

Comment: I Think @Jim what you have answered makes sense and for the specific business logic of Correlating between SET9 and SET1 would work and i would not need to post processing using spark for that. But i have a followup  question on DataLocality using the approach of PRIMARY KEY((sensor_id, SensorEventType), created_at) this would mean data for  (SensorId_1, SET1) can possibly be on a different Cassandra Node than the (SensorId_1, SET9) right ?

Comment: Yes, those partitions would likely be on different nodes.  So if you did a join in spark between those partitions, it would involve shuffling some of the data over the network.  But that would probably be more efficient than loading millions of unneeded data points into memory just to then discard them with a filter.